# Node.js: How to handle multiple validate with validator.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

I found [validator.js](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) but I'm not sure how I should validate multiple values.

With [validate.js](http://validatejs.org/#constraints) I can define constraints and then just run `validate(myDataObject, constraints)` and it returns errors or success.

However with [validator.js](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) I would need to do something like:

```
if(validator.isEmail(myData.email) && validator.isURL(myData.url)) {
    // success
}
```

With many variables this could get messy, especially when the same conditions are required multiple places.

Any idea what I could do instead of using `if` to validate many fields?

Comment: The reason I want to use validator.js instead of validate.js is because validator.js includes built-in validation that validate.js doesn't have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your own validators

```
validator.extend('isAwesomeEmail', function (myData) {
    return validator.isEmail(myData.email) &&
        validator.isUrl(myData.url);
});

validator.extend('isSuperAwesomeEmail', function (myData) {
    return validator.isAwesomeEmail(myData) &&
        myData.awesome === true;
});

validator.isAwesomeEmail(myData);
validator.isSuperAwesomeEmail(myData);
```